# Оптимизация хранения данных в БД MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица в MySQL, которая хранит в себе сообщения пользователей. ***(_id, from_id, to_id, date, content)***
Т.е. все сообщения со всех переписок будут сохраняться в этой таблице. Я понимаю, что это совершенно нерационально и неправильно, ведь загрузка переписки из сервера реализована простым SELECT'ом по from_id и сортировкой по date.
Так вот, как можно рационально составить таблицу для хранения переписки пользователей, чтобы запросы к БД не были слишком долгими при большом кол-ве сообщений?

Comment: Таблица оставлена верно. в реляционных БД других способов представления нет. Почему вы считаете, что выборка будет долгой ? Если делать составной индекс из полей (from_id, date) и в сортировке указать так же по оба этих поля в этом же порядке то должно быть быстро.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы у вас была задача вывода сообщений пользователей в виде *древовидных* комментариев - тогда у вас была бы возможность использовать один из трёх способов хранения в базе: обычный Adjacency List, Nested Set или Materialized Path. Эта тема много где освещается в сети, например тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/46659/

А так у вас другую структуру базы особо-то и не придумаешь, Mike верно сказал.

Я когда-то ковырял популярные движки форумов и во многих есть ограничения на размер ящика для личных сообщений -- скажем, всем по 50. Подозреваю, что эти лимиты как раз введены, чтобы для больших форумов держать нагрузку на сервер в приличных пределах.

Хотя вот у меня она практически не ощущается, хоть и база достаточно распухла уже за несколько лет: всё же выборка по to_id (для входящих сообщений) или from_id (для отправленных) вполне эффективно отсекает достаточно много тредов.